# Embedding web page into industrial pc

Tags: c#, python, web

I’m looking for a way to embed a single page style web application into an industrial pc that’s running TwinCAT 3 plc to control an automation system.  The hmi on this system is already written in c# using the beckhoff ads dll.  What I’m having trouble with is how to embed the server that’s reading and writing data to my plc instance and the web page front end into one application.  I’m looking to use c# or python as those are the languages that I have experience in.  I would like to be able to log into this webpage by the up address of the Pc and get a page on a phone or laptop that allows elements on the screen to be interacted with like buttons and a joystick style control for creating motion on the machine.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS is the PLC running on? If WinCE, its a bit trickier. You'll need VS2008 to compile against the NET35CF for C#.

With a "full" version of windows, things become simpler - you can use whichever version of .NET will fit on the controller, or whichever version of Python supports the [python ADS library](https://github.com/stlehmann/pyads).

After that, create your connections into the PLC as per the [Beckhoff ADS examples](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcsample/html/tcsample_intro.htm?id=2105283098444985027) when required by your web page.

Of course you will need to manage the web server accordingly. Some Beckhoff PLCs already use IIS for basic diagnostics, so you would have to set up an appropriate route to your page to avoid conflict.